# new to jolt json need inputs on transformations

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I  have to inject data using curl with the said payload, for this I am using JOLT transformations to create a json.  I want to transform below json:

```
[
  {
    "value_schema_id": "XXXXXXX",
    "system_code": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "event_type": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "metric_name": "XXXXXXX",
    "metric_id": "1",
    "global_person_profile_id": "2",
    "create_ts": "3"
  },
  {
    "value_schema_id": "XXXXXXX",
    "system_code": "XXXXXXX",
    "event_type": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "metric_name": "XXXXXXX",
    "metric_id": "1",
    "global_person_profile_id": "2",
    "create_ts": "3"
  }
]
```

In the form of

```
{ 
  "value_schema_id": XXXXXX, 
  "records": 
    [ { "value": { 
     "system_code": "XXXXXX",
     "event_type": "XXXXXX", 
     "event_detail": { 
        "metric_name": "XXXXXX", 
        "metric_id": "XXXXXX", 
        "global_person_profile_id": "XXXXXX", 
        "create_ts": "XXXXXX" } 
} } ] }
```

I came this far,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value_schema_id": "value_schema_id",
      "*": {
        "system_code": "records[&1].system_code",
        "event_type": "records[&1].event_type",
        "metric_name": "records[&1].metric_name",
        "metric_id": "records[&1].metric_id",
        "global_person_profile_id": "records[&1].global_person_profile_id",
        "create_ts": "records[&1].create_ts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "records[]": {
        "*": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But the default operation is not fetching the values as desired.  I appreciate any input. thanks!

Comment: "But the default operation is not fetching the values as desired" What inputs are you trying and what output are you getting?

Comment: Hi zovits, In the above post  json mentioned on the top is my input and below is the one below is the expected output. I am not able to post it here, or else I would have. I hope you can find it now.

Comment: Hi Zovits! I am able to achieve what I am looking for, now I need to remove null from the output json. input json: